# Xcode Project Localized to Portuguese (Brazil), why still show English?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, localization

My Xcode project is localized to "Portuguese (Brazil)", then I tried to set language to "Portuguese" and "Portuguese (Portugal)" on device and simulator, but the interface still show English, what's wrong?

Other localized languages work well, only Brazil failed to work. I wonder what language setting would Brazil people choose?

Comment: Dumb question I know, but needs to be asked. You did add the new strings in portuguese right? and you didn't just copy in a new file or anything like that, you used xcode to add the language and the files and then modified the file yourself?

Comment: yes, I localized to french and german successfully. Not sure why Brazil fail to work.

Comment: I am not sure about this because I have never done country specific localization, but is there any particular reason for using _Portuguese (Brazil)_ instead of _Portuguese_? _Portuguese (Brazil)_ and _Portuguese (Portugal)_ are different languages. And _Portuguese (Brazil)_ is not _Portugese_, at least not for computers, if iOS wants Portuguese it won't use the Brazil variant. Usually you want to localize in the least specific language first, in your case _Portuguese_. If iOS wants Brazilian Portuguese and it can't find it it will use "normal" Portuguese.

Comment: i want to localize for Brazil people, so what I choose Portuguese (Brazil) in xcode, but there is no "Portuguese (Brazil)" in iOS setting.. I tried both "Portuguese" and "Portuguese (Portugal)", but it show English.

Comment: Yes. Brazilian Portuguese is very different from Portugese. While they are mutually intelligible it is at least as distinct as US vs UK English.

Comment: But there is no "Portuguese (Brazil)" in iPhone's setting. So what would Brazilian choose? "Portuguese" or "Portuguese (Portugal)"??

Comment: This is a complete stab in the dark here, what about setting language to portuguese and setting location to Brazil ? I've also noticed there is a region format option inside international settings, the portuguese option expands and has Brazil inside that. Maybe play around with those settings too ?

Comment: Tried, still not working, I wonder Brazilian may simply choose "Portuguese", since there is no "Portuguese (Brazil)" in iOS, but why Xcode provide "Portuguese (Brazil)" option??  It is so confusing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked some coders, in Xcode, they just localize to "Portuguese" and skip "Portuguese (Brazil)". No idea why Apple would make such a difference between iOS and Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same issue and I am able to make my project work correctly now. I would say this is happening because of the way xCode provides us options to select Portuguese Brazil.

Actually this line from Apple Documentation helped me:

The language ID for scripts or dialects uses subtags, as in pt-PT where pt is the code for Portuguese and PT is the code for Portugal. For example, use pt as the language ID for Portuguese as it is used in Brazil and pt-PT as the language ID for Portuguese as it is used in Portugal.

For Brazil Portuguese select only Portuguese language (pt) and not Brazil Portuguese. For Portugal Portuguese, you can select Portuguese Portugal (pt-PT). It will work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find that for languages with a bracket in the name, it does not work if you spell it out.

For Portuguese (Brazil), you'll have to use pt-BR.

e.g. ~AppleLanguages("pt-BR")

Just like for Chinese (Traditional) & Chinese (Simplified), you have to use
~AppleLanguages("zh-Hant") and ~AppleLanguages("zh-Hans")

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like these languages just reversed their placed.
When I use "pt" it works for brazilian portuguese, but not for Portugal portuguese. Solution is to duplicate "pt" and "pt-BR" in our translation. Weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter that there is no "Portuguese" option on the phones, but only "Portuguese (Brazil)" and "Portuguese (Portugal)".  The localization specification is a hierarchy. The intended approach is to implement the most general aspects first (ex: Portuguese), and then add additional differentiation based on Region, Country, Script, etc as needed.

Some reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html